# Can items in Microsemi Libero SmartDesign canvas be rotated?

Tags: schematics, ide, libero

I am sure there is a way to rotate or flip the things we put into the canvas of the Microsemi Libero SmartDesign Canvas but it is not clear how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl R maybe???

Comment: did not work, libero is not intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Microsemi has confirmed that the SmartDesign canvas lacks capability to rotate or flip the symbols used in it. The symbols can only face one way and not be rotated or flipped.